# Its possible to change SPTreeView icons?

Tags: navigation

I've an customized SPTreeView(UC) but I'm realizing that is not the best way to go, cause it seams limited to further customizations as, for example, **setting custom icons** for each SPWeb (event if they have their own webTemplate).

ideas, suggestions or even other navigation options are welcome!

spregards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few posts that show the use of the SPTreeView that may be helpful to you -

- [How to: Use TreeView in Current Navigation in SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32389/How-to-Use-TreeView-in-Current-Navigation-in-Share)
- [SharePoint Folder TreeView](http://balmikighosh.blogspot.com/2012/04/sharepoint-folder-treeview.html)
- [SharePoint Manager 2010 (CodePlex)](http://spm.codeplex.com/) - an excellent project to learn SharePoint development techniques

SPTreeView has properties - ExpandImageUrl, CollapseImageUrl & NoExpandImageUrl that can be provided with the URL to the custom icons.

Comment: hanks a lot for the reply, but setting those properties are for the expand image, not for the spweb icon. rgds

Comment: how are you using the SPTreeView control (page, navigation, etc) in your application?

Comment: UC with SPHierarchyDataSourceControl and SPTreeView placed in the master. And I'm using it as a SPSite global navigation, or at least I intend to...